# How to check if object is JProperty or JArray

Tags: json.net

Given the two JTokens:

```
{ "Users": { "Name": "Carl" } }
```

and

```
{ "Users": [ { "Name": "Carl" }, {"Name": "Peter"} ] }
```

How can I tell if Users is a JProperty or JObject/JArray?

I need loop Users with

```
foreach (JObject User in myjobject["Users"]) { ... }
```

**Solution**
It was as simple as myjobject["Users"].GetType(). However, that didn't work in the Watch debugger window, but it worked at runtime. Hrmpff.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Type](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Type.htm) property will tell you the type of the token you have.

```
switch(token.Type)
{
     case JTokenType.Array:
         break;
     case JTokenType.String:
         break;
}
```

Comment: Tks! It works for me. if (item.list.Type == JTokenType.Array)