# How to find out if a JProperty of a JObject is an Array or not?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to get every property of a class and print it including arrays(expanded with the respective index). If I do as following, I see that if an array occurs, it prints the array's name.

```cs
foreach (JProperty property in localJson.Properties())
{
    Console.WriteLine("NAME :" + property.Name + "======================");
}
```

But I wish to print all array elements with their indices for which I should be able to identify if the property is an Array or not. I tried doing it as below,

```cs
foreach (JProperty property in localJson.Properties())
{
    JToken propertyToken = property;
    if (propertyToken is JArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Array"); //Further Manipulations
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NAME :" + property.Name);
    }
}
```

But I still see that `propertyToken` is of type `Property` and hence missing the `if`.
Is there any other way to do this?

EDIT : My question differs from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172549/how-to-check-if-object-is-jproperty-or-jarray) because my question is to check if a JProperty of a JObject is an Array or not and not if a JToken is a Jproperty or JArray.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172549/how-to-check-if-object-is-jproperty-or-jarray

Comment: is checks if the instance of propertyToken belongs to a speicfic .NET class/interface. I doubt it applies to...however Json arrays are defined after parsing

Comment: Just looking at this class (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm), HasValues, Count and ChildrenToken are propably the droids you are looking for.

Comment: @SalahAkbari I tried more or less the same way. Still, the type of my `propertyToken` is `Property` even if its an array.

Comment: @Christopher yes thank you for the insight. I got the count of the `ChildrenTokens` which would help me to identify if its an array or not. Idk why I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is currently asking whether a `JProperty` is a `JArray`.  The answer to that is always no.  `JProperty` does not derive from `JArray`.  (Both derive from `JToken`.)

What you really want to be asking is whether the *value* of the `JProperty` is a `JArray`.

```
JToken propertyValue = property.Value;
if (propertyValue.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Array"); //Further Manipulations
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("NAME :" + property.Name);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realised and did the same. Thank you.